# Confusion About Rigorously Defining Conservation of Quantum Information in Terms of Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information

I'm trying to understand the principle of conservation of information in quantum theory and what it actually means. I've been reading [this paper (Horodecki et al 2005)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0407038.pdf), in it they derive the no-cloning and no-deleting theorems with just the assumption of information conservation (not from unitarity). They only assume that the dynamics is linear (which is an even weaker assumption than convex-linearity that I've seen in textbooks), and that an external system can be added as long as it doesn't contain information about the principal system.

If I'm not mistaken, they define the conservation of information to mean that if $\rho_{in}$ is the input state and $\rho_{out}$ is the output state, then

$$S[\rho_{in}]=S[\rho_{out}]$$

(for the von Neumann entropy). Then basically they show that then $S[\rho_{in}]<S[\rho_{out}]$ implies the no-cloning theorem (even with the added external system), and that for a closed system, $S[\rho_{in}]>S[\rho_{out}]$ implies the no-deleting theorem.

Doesn't that definition contradict the second law of thermodynamics though? I can see how $S[\rho_{in}]>S[\rho_{out}]$ in a closed system violates the 2nd law of thermodynamics, leading to the no-deleting theorem, but doesn't $S[\rho_{in}]=S[\rho_{out}]$ in general violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics (assuming the universe as a whole is a closed system)?

Also, either way, is conservation of information purely about unitary evolution? Does unitary imply information conservation or does information conservation (however you rigorously define it) imply unitary?